# User gets logged in automatically when resetting password

Tags: next.js, supabase

I'm trying to develop a password reset process with Next.js (13.4) and Supabase Auth.

##### Issue:

After the user clicks on the password reset link received via email, **if they refresh the page, they automatically get logged in.**

[**Watch the issue in a GIF**](https://i.ibb.co/jLLY5Y5/Recording-2023-05-08-at-21-41-14.gif)

##### Expect:

There's no problem as long as they don't refresh the page, but I don't want them to log in without resetting their password first.

##### A Solution:

> Your update password form should be in the logged in area and not in
> the auth area as the user has to be logged in to change their
> password.

from [GitHub/supabase](https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/14209#discussioncomment-5849761)

##### What I did:

My `layout.js` (children: login, register, password and reset):

```js
import { createServerComponentSupabaseClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { headers, cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'

export default async function AuthLayout({ children }) {
    const supabase = createServerComponentSupabaseClient({
        headers,
        cookies,
    })
    const { data } = await supabase.auth.getSession()

    if (data.session) {
        redirect('/admin')
    } // This causes the issue, but I cannot remove it.

    return children
}
```

My `<SupabaseProvider>`:

```js
'use client'

import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { createBrowserSupabaseClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

const Context = createContext(undefined)

export default function SupabaseProvider({ children }) {
    const [supabase] = useState(() => createBrowserSupabaseClient())
    const router = useRouter()

    useEffect(() => {
        const {
            data: { subscription },
        } = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
            console.log("EVENT (provider) => ", event)

            if (event === 'PASSWORD_RECOVERY') {
                router.push('/admin/auth/reset')
            }

            if (session && (event === 'SIGNED_IN' || event == 'TOKEN_REFRESHED')) {
                router.refresh()
            }

            if (event === 'SIGNED_OUT') {
                router.refresh()
            }

        })

        return () => {
            subscription.unsubscribe()
        }
    }, [router, supabase])

    return (
        <Context.Provider value={{ supabase }}>
            <>{children}</>
        </Context.Provider>
    )
}

export const useSupabase = () => {
    const context = useContext(Context)

    if (context === undefined) {
        throw new Error('useSupabase must be used inside SupabaseProvider')
    }

    return context
}
```

Console output (*After clicking the password reset link, and then if refresh, they automatically get logged in*):

```bash
EVENT (provider) => INITIAL_SESSION
EVENT (provider) => PASSWORD_RECOVERY
```

[image: console-output]

DOCS:

- [Supabase - Listen to auth events](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-onauthstatechange)
- [Supabase - Send a password reset request](https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/auth-resetpasswordforemail)

Comment: As soon as the user clicks on the password recovery link, they are signed in. That is how Supabase works currently. 

What you can do is to not redirect the user automatically when the user is on the password reset page.

Comment: @dshukertjr Yes, I didn't know that. Anyway, I built my reset pages like that for now, it works as I wish if user doesn't refresh the page. Thanks.